# Is there a way to explicitly enable/disable Java compiler to reorder instructions?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning Java concurrency and know that the following singleton is not completely thread safe. A thread may get instance before it is initialized because of instructions reordering. A correct way to prevent this potential problem is to use volatile keyword.

```
public class DoubleCheckedLocking {
    private static Instance instance;
    public static Instance getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DoubleCheckedLocking.class) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new Instance();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I tried to reproduce the potential problem without volatile keyword and wrote a demo to show that using the above code may cause a NullPointerException in multithreading environment. But I failed to find a way to explicitly let the Java compiler perform instructions reordering and my demo with the above singleton always works pretty well without any problems.

So my question is how to explicitly enable/disable Java compiler to reorder instructions or how to reproduce the problem without using volatile keyword in a double-checked locking singleton?

Comment: Not that it's not just the JIT that might do reordering; it's also things like CPU caches flushing across cores.

Comment: Note also that the fact that double-checked locking can fail says nothing about how likely you are to be able to *observe* a failure.

Answer (score 2):

The dangerous thing here is not necessarily, that other threads may receive `null` as an answer from `getInstance`. The dangerous thing is, that they may observe an instance, which is not (yet) properly initialized.

To check this, add a few fields to your singleton, say:

```
class Singleton {

    private List<Object> members;

    private Singleton() {
        members = new ArrayList<>();
        members.addAll(queryMembers());
    }

    private Collection<Object> queryMembers() {
        return Arrays.asList("Hello", 1, 2L, "world", new Object());
    }

    public int size() {
        return members.size();
    }

    private static Singleton instance = null;

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DoubleCheckedLocking.class) {
                if (instance == null)
                    instance = new Singleton();
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

This is called "unsafe publication". Other threads may see the singleton instance partially initialized (i.e., the `members` field may still be `null`, or the list may be empty, or only partially filled, or worse: in an inconsistent state due to an object just being added).

In the example code above, no external caller of `size` should ever see a value different from 5, right? I didn't try it, but I wouldn't be surprised, if callers can observe different values, if the timing isn't right.

The reason for this is, that the compiler is allowed to translate

```
instance = new Singleton();
```

into something along the lines of

```
instance = allocate_instance(Singleton.class);   // pseudo-code
instance.<init>();
```

and thus, we have a window, in which `instance` is no longer `null`, but the actual object is not yet properly initialized.

[The "Double-Checked Locking is Broken" Declaration](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) gives an in-depth explanation of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from the [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) book:

> Debugging tip: For server applications, be sure to always specify the
>   -server JVM command line switch when invoking the JVM, even for development and testing. The server JVM performs more optimization
>   than the client JVM, such as hoisting variables out of a loop that are
>   not modified in the loop; code that might appear to work in the
>   development environment (client JVM) can break in the deployment
>   environment (server JVM). For example, had we "forgotten" to declare
>   the variable asleep as volatile in Listing 3.4, the server JVM could
>   hoist the test out of the loop (turning it into an infinite loop), but
>   the client JVM would not. An infinite loop that shows up in
>   development is far less costly than one that only shows up in
>   production.

So you can give it a try. But there is no 100% sure way of enabling reordering.